# Send res json in return of request [nodeJs]

Tags: json, node.js, request

I want to send a res.json in the return of a request, used in an Api

```
    api.app.get('/url', function(req, res) {

    request({
            url: "http://localhost:3001/myUrl", method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "application/json",
                'Accept': "application/json",

            }
        }

        , function (err, stdout, body) {
            console.log(err)
            console.log(body)

            res.json({success:true, data:"raed"})
        })
});
```

This `res.json({success:true, data:"raed"})` is not executed.
but the two `console.log`, are executed successfully.
Is there a solution please ?

Comment: any error or something?

Comment: no there isn't any error

Comment: After the console log, and after a time, ther is this error : 

 Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:302:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:394:23)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9) code: 'ECONNRESET' }

Comment: The error you have wrote is caused not by the code you posted here.
May you post a script of the main node file?

Did you include body parser module?
If not try adding, search at Google for this.
Also, add next after the req, res in the received params.